# Treating index of a list as a integer

Tags: python, list, indexing, integer

I'm doing some sample programming challenges to practice for a upcoming competition, and I've found myself stumped on a rather easy challenge.

Basically, the user has to enter x amount of numbers, and I have to return the sum of the numbers. The condition is that every time they enter 0, it means i have to disregard the last number that they entered, so it will not be apart of the sum anymore.

Here is my code:

```
numbers = []
index = 0
total = 0

k = input("How many numbers would you like to enter? (1- 100000)" + "\n").strip()

for x in range (int(k)):
    number = input("Enter a number." + "\n").strip()
    numbers.append(number)
    if number == '0':
        index = numbers.index(number)
        numbers.pop([index - 1])
        numbers.pop([index])

for y in range (len(numbers)):
    for item in numbers:
        total += int(item)


print(total)
```

error on this line:

```
numbers.pop([index - 1])
```

It tells me that 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I originally tried to make it int(index) hoping that it would convert it into an int so i can carry out the subtraction to get the index of the number before it so i can pop it out of the list, but I got the same error message.

Is there any way to use this value as an integer so I can carry out the subtract one. Or is there a different way required to get the index of the number before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think `[index - 1]` is? It's obviously a `list`. And that's not an integer. `index - 1`, without the square brackets, would be an integer. Also, you should check for whether the user's number is `0` *before* appending it, or the last value in the `list` will be that `0` rather than the value you need to remove, which just makes for extra work.

There's also a lot of room for improvement in your code, along the lines of making proper use of built-ins and eliminating unnecessary counters:

```
k = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter? (1- 100000)\n"))
result = []
for i in range(k):
    num = int(input("Enter a number.\n"))
    if num:
        result.append(num)
    elif result:
        result.pop(-1)

print(sum(result))
```

Comment: Wow, that way looks so much more clean. Although I would like some clarification on this. in your elif result statement, how does that translate to if the number they entered is 0, do this:

Comment: Wait nevermind, I thought about it for a bit and I understand, thanks for this!

Comment: `if num:` passes with a truthy `num`, which is any number besides `0`. At `elif result:`, we know that the number was `0`, so we then check whether `result` has items in it by making sure it's truthy. We can then safely remove an item from it.

Answer (score 2):

well, in python, one can refer to elements at the *end* of the list with negative numbers:

```
>>> l = range(10, 100, 5)
>>> l
[10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95]
>>> l[-1]
95
>>> l[-2]
90
```

and pop will take these negative numbers, so to delete the second to last item in the list is just:

```
>>> l.pop(-2)
90
>>> l
[10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 95]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `numbers.pop(index - 1)`

What you have to do is to pass the integer value of the index that needs to be popped, rather than passing a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
numbers = []
index = 0
total = 0

k = input("How many numbers would you like to enter? (1- 100000)" + "\n").strip()

for x in range (int(k)):
    number = input("Enter a number." + "\n").strip()
    numbers.append(number)
    if number == '0':
        index = numbers.index(number)
        numbers.pop(index - 1)
        numbers.pop(index)

for y in range (len(numbers)):
    for item in numbers:
        total += int(item)


print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list, when you should pass an int

```
numbers.pop(index-1)
```

code:

```
numbers = []
index = 0
total = 0

k = input("How many numbers would you like to enter? (1- 100000)" + "\n").strip()

for x in range (int(k)):
    number = input("Enter a number." + "\n").strip()
    numbers.append(number)
    if number == '0':
        index = numbers.index(number)
        numbers.pop(index)
        numbers.pop(index-1)
for y in range (len(numbers)):
    for item in numbers:
        total += int(item)


print(total)
```

And if I may, this is an easier way of doing it

```
total = 0
last = 0
k = input("How many numbers would you like to enter? (1- 100000)" + "\n").strip()

for x in range (int(k)):
    print("Enter Number")
    temp = int(input())
    total += temp
    if temp == 0:
        total -= last
    else:
        last = temp
print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Your version has a problem though. The user can enter 2 consecutive 0s if they like. So I would need to find a way to have another temporary variable that stores the new final number after the previous one is removed, which is why i opted to try and use a list and go through the index of the list.

Comment: I assumed that the user wont enter more than one zero at a time